# Свет в Three JS

Tags: javascript, three.js, освещение

Создал сцену в Three JS и мне нужно динамично добавлять PointLight, но при нажатии на кнопку он не светит. А если написать добавление света в самом теле кода, когда создается меш куба, то всё работает нормально. В чём проблема?

http://jsfiddle.net/bhp8ox5x/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После подобных изменений нужно выставить у всех материалов сцены `needsUpdate=true;`

Comment: Угу, вот недавно наткнулся на такое. Но теперь другой вопрос, есть ли в Three JS "хранилище" материалов со всей сцены. Или нужно проходиться по всем материалам и выставлять true у всех по отдельности?

Comment: нет, "кучи" со всеми инициализированными материалами нет, придется по всем объектам пройтись

Comment: @Ni55aN не пашет. http://jsfiddle.net/bhp8ox5x/3/

Comment: @Perkovec, пашет, просто цвет куба - зеленый, а цвет освещения "не зеленый", и поэтому нет никакого эффекта. В Суперкниге по OpenGL есть об этом в разделе "Теория света"
Выводы: сделать PointLight белым
П.С. для отладки лучше использовать console.log(), это дает больше преимуществ при отладке

Comment: Всё, спасибо большое. Всё отлично работает) Для отладки всегда использую консоль хрома (jsfiddle для написания примера, а так всё у меня на компе) и this. переменные.